# jquery .find() does not find an xml node

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, parsing

No matter what I try, I cannot find an XML node in an .ajax response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ctatt>
    <tmst>20121209 09:58:14</tmst>
    <errCd>0</errCd>
    <errNm />
    <eta>
        <staId>40970</staId>
        <stpId>30188</stpId>
        <staNm>Cicero</staNm>
        <stpDe>Service toward Forest Park</stpDe>
        <rn>105</rn>
        <rt>Blue</rt>
        <destSt>0</destSt>
        <destNm>Forest Park</destNm>
        <trDr>5</trDr>
        <prdt>20121209 09:57:40</prdt>
        <arrT>20121209 10:00:40</arrT>
        <isApp>0</isApp>
        <isSch>0</isSch>
        <isDly>0</isDly>
        <isFlt>0</isFlt>
        <flags />
    </eta>
</ctatt>
```

`$(response).find('ctatt').find('eta').each(function(){});` will not find the ela nodes. It never enters the each loop.

`$(response).find('ctatt').find('tmst')` or `$(response).find('ctatt').find('errCd')` does enter the each loop. I do not understand why it can't parse `$(response).find('ctatt').find('eta')`

Comment: Where are you getting that XML from, did you parse it as XML with [**$.parseXML**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml = $.parseXML(response);

$(xml).find('ctatt').find('eta').each(function(i,elem){
    console.log(elem);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9mJbq/30/)

Comment: XML is returned from a web service. This code works perfectly in Fiddle. However, it does not enter the each loop in Phonegap app.